# Is a bracha said when eating non-food items (e.g. paper)?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

If someone wants to eat something that is not considered food (e.g. paper), is a bracha required? Obviously if one is, it would be shehacol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This article](https://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/3-When-is-a-Bracha-Not-Required.html) is quite detailed on explaining when you don't need to make a bracha. The article contains source references, as well.

Excerpts:

> A bracha is recited when we experience pleasure from eating the food
> that God has provided. This primarily includes pleasure due to “taste”
> – i.e. pleasure in the mouth or throat.
>
> Similarly, if a food is in a state where it is not fit for human
> consumption, it does not require a bracha because it is not considered
> food. A few examples:
>
> - raw potatoes
> - raw rice, raw peppercorns
> - fruits that are [bitter or sour and] completely unripe
> - spoiled or burned foods
>
> The general rule is: If most people would not eat such a food even if
> they were really hungry, then no bracha is required. For example, the
> Guinness Book of World Records claims that someone once ate an entire
> bicycle over a period of months. If he was Jewish, he would not have
> said a bracha when eating the bicycle.

(I met someone years ago, who claimed that he ate everything on his plate, LITERALLY. This included eating the flatware! We didn't believe him until x-rays confirmed that his stomach had spoons, knives and forks in there. Let's just say that after a few days, he "forked over" his food :-) :-)

Comment: I suppose paper qualifies as something that most people don't eat.

Comment: A bicycle? Really? [This guy ate an airplane.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Lotito)

Comment: Was the bicycle hechshered?  Did he inspect it for bugs?

Comment: @Charles "**if** he was Jewish".

Comment: @Scimonster a bicycle is the R' Chaim Naeh shiur; an airplane is the Chazon Ish shiur.

Comment: Three questions: 1. How would this apply to someone with pica, for whom eating non-food is pleasurable and provides needed nutrients, 2. If someone chews on a piece of leather (and swallows saliva) because he enjoys the sensation, is there a bracha and 2a, even if there is no bracha, is he fleishig?